# Nuxt: Command 'nuxt' not found - Output directory `dist/` does not exists

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, nuxtjs

I have successfully created a Nuxt.js project with this configuration using the CLI:

```
Project name: test
Programming language: JavaScript
Package manager: Npm
UI framework: None
Nuxt.js modules: None
Linting tools: None
Testing framework: None
Rendering mode: Single Page App
Deployment target: Static (Static/JAMStack hosting)
Development tools: jsconfig.json
Version control system: Git
```

The developement server runs properly with `npm run dev`.
`npm run build` also runs without errors and tells me that:

```
Ready to run nuxt generate
```

But the execution of `nuxt generate` leads to the error `Command 'nuxt' not found`. This is strange because nuxt seems to be installed when I execute `npm nuxt list`.

[image: nuxt not found]

I first reinstalled just nuxt and then all dependencies after deleting the `node_modules/` folder, but the error remains the same. If I just run `npm run start` it tells me

```
Nuxt Fatal Error
Error: Output directory `dist/` does not exists, please use
`nuxt generate` before `nuxt start` for static target.
```

This is strange again because the .nuxt/dist/ folder exists.
Does anyone have an idea what is going wrong?

[image: dist/ does not exist]

[image: dist/ exists]

Answer (score 13):

I have solved the problem. For me it works if I run `npm run generate` instead of `nuxt generate`.